# Team git flow with testing in mind

Tags: git, bitbucket, workflow, branching-and-merging

We have planned a git workflow that we thought would work well but are having problems.

**In SourceTree**
We have 4 main branches

1. **_dev** (from which we create feature-branches, each feature branch corresponds to a JIRA task)
2. **_qa** (to which we merge feature-branches once features are ready and code reviewed on _dev)
3. **_next-release** (to which we merge the feature branch when a feature is approved by QA)
4. **master** (to which we merge the entire **_next-release** branch when the sprint is over, thereby merging only the approved features)

We also have **version branches** to which we merge the master branch when a version is released (we do this to make sure we can return to that branch and make adjustments if necessary as our product is an installable one)

Our problematic scenario is:

1. Dev1 creates feature1 (branch from _dev)
2. Dev1 merges feature1 to _dev (let's say it's waiting for code review at this point)
3. Dev1 creates and starts working on feature2 (branch from _dev again)
4. Dev1 merges feature2 into _dev and passes code review.
5. Dev1 attempts to merge feature2 to _qa

**Result**: both feature1 and feature2 seem to merge into QA, even though feature1 is not ready yet.

We merge by right clicking the branch and picking "merge featureX into current branch"

Please note we have 4 environments that (should) reflect each branch so QA have a place to check features.

**Why** are features being merged together with features we did not want to merge?

**What** is the common workflow that will allow merging only validated features into a version while allowing QA an environment to check features and allow for a clean history that will reflect each feature's lifecycle - dev -> QA -> release -> version

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, a word of caution:  If you stick with this workflow, and resolve your current issues, you will face other, subtler issues.  Workflows like this, which try to go back to merges of individual feature branches at multiple stages of the development life cycle, run into trouble because they ignore the possible interactions between changes on different branches.

With that said, let's focus on some of your questions.  Your scenario (with illustrations) looks like this:

First off, you have `_dev` and `_qa` branches.  (The others, we'll set aside for the moment, for simplicity.)

```
A -- B -- C <--(_dev)(_qa)
```

I'm assuming that we start in a state where everything in `_dev` has passed `_qa` (and of course everything that has passed `_qa` should be in `_dev`), so they're pointing at the same commit.  This may leave out some complicating factors that would impede your workflow, but it still gives us enough to understand the problem you currently face.  Now

> Dev1 creates feature1

```
A -- B -- C <--(_dev)(_qa)
           \
            D -- E <--(feature1)
```

> Dev1 merges feature1 to _dev (let's say it's waiting for code review at this point)

```
        (_qa)
          |
A -- B -- C ------ M1<--(_dev)
           \      /
            D -- E <--(feature1)
```

> Dev1 creates and starts working on feature2

```
        (_qa)         F -- G <--(feature2)
          |          /
A -- B -- C ------ M1<--(_dev)
           \      /
            D -- E <--(feature1)
```

> Dev1 merges feature2 into _dev and passes code review.

```
        (_qa)         F -- G <--(feature2)
          |          /      \
A -- B -- C ------ M1 ------ M2 <--(_dev)
           \      /
            D -- E <--(feature1)
```

> Dev1 attempts to merge feature2 to _qa

Ok, so what happens here?  Well, `feature2` is a descendant of `_qa` (since we started with `_qa` and `_dev` in the same place).  So you could fast-forward `_qa` to `feature2` (and even if you don't, the resulting merge commit will have the same content as if you had).  But `feature2` was rooted at `M1`; the changes from `feature1` are *reachable from* `feature2` but *not reachable from* `_qa`, so the merge would include them.

If we had started with `_qa` being reachable from `_dev` (rather than the two pointing at the same commit), exactly the same analysis would hold.  If, for some reason, `_qa` contained changes *not* reachable form `_dev`, we could have something like

```
       Q <--(_qa)     F -- G <--(feature2)
      /              /      \
A -- B -- C ------ M1 ------ M2 <--(_dev)
           \      /
            D -- E <--(feature1)
```

In that case, git would find a merge base between `_qa` and `feature2` - i.e. a common ancestor.  That would be `B`.  It would then combine "changes between `B` and `_qa`" with "changes between `B` and `feature2`.  Again, the changes between `B` and `feature2` *include the changes that were made by `feature1`* because `feature2` was rooted at `M1` (i.e. a point after `feature1` was merged in).

In all cases, the point is the same:  For the most part (including during a merge), git does not view commits (or deltas between them) as "belonging to" this branch or that branch.  Instead it cares about whether a change is on the path to the merge base.

One situation where git *can* typically be made to look at the changes "from a branch" in isolation would be a `rebase`.  However, your workflow would need a major overhaul to take advantage of this, and it would lead to other complications.  It isn't the path I would recommend here.

Another way it might seem you could patch up your workflow would be to require developers to start new feature branches at the merge base between `_dev` and `_qa`.  **BUT** this may only kick the can down the road (unless changes will always "stay in order" once they reach `_qa`, which is not a reasonable assumption - especially if QA ever discovers defects).  Besides, this increases the isolation between work done for one feature vs the next feature, ultimately meaning you'll probably have more merge conflicts to deal with.

Anyway, I think that addresses your **why** question.  As for the **what**:

Well, while you've used "git flow" as a generic term for "a branching and merging strategy", actually git flow is the name of a *specific* branching and merging strategy.  I suggest reading up on it.  The needs you've outlined are not unique or even uncommon, so instead of thinking you have to customize this flow to meet those needs, look into how people meet those needs using this flow.

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for the detailed answer :)
I have looked into GitFlow and the question remains - how can we merge "forward" only approved features?
As far as I see - in GitFlow you stabilize the develop branch and then branch off a version off of it, what if it's the end of the sprint and 1 feature hasn't been tested?

Thanks! :)

Comment: @EdoMagen Then the untested feature doesn't belong in the `dev` branch.

Comment: Then where does QA take place?
We have automatic deployment for every merge to _dev and _qa.
_dev is our integration environment and _qa is what's being tested, each branch is reflected in a subdomain in our company (dev.xxx.xxx and qa.xxx.xxx)
Is there another option to QA and approve each feature before merging?

Comment: @EdoMagen - The most common answer I see is to back-merge dev to the feature branch and deploy that result to the QA environment.  (That way you're testing the candidate feature with everything that's already QA'd and nothing else.)  IMO there's not a "perfect" answer with any workflow because you can't address every combination of features that could become important.  The key point is that merging to a long-lived branch should be a committed statement about a level of release-readiness, because backing out the merge (w/o throwing away the branch) isn't so easy